# C# WPF ListBox mouse click is late

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, listitem, mouseclick-event

I am trying to have the text in a `TextBlock` update with the text from a `ListBox` item when I left-click that item.

My C# code:

```
private void listBox_MouseDown_rem(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (pathListB.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        rem_block.Text = pathListB.SelectedValue.ToString();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
 <ListBox Name="pathListB" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="listBox_MouseDown_rem" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="246" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="491"/>
 <TextBlock Name="rem_block" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,261,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Select Item to Remove" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="20" Width="411"/>
```

Now all of this does what it's supposed to, except that when I select a `ListBoxItem` (I have a loop elsewhere populating this `ListBox`) it only updates to my previous value on my next mouse click, so it's always "late."

So for example my listbox has these items:

```
Sentence 1
Sentence 2
Sentence 3
```

I will click on "Sentence 1", and my `TextBlock` doesn't change. I click on "Sentence 3", and `TextBlock` updates to "Sentence 1," etc. It always updates to the previous value.

Comment: PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown happens before select.  Use the mouse down event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On PreviewMouseDown, the ListBox item hasn't been changed yet. Use the PreviewMouseUp event instead, which will fire when the item has already been changed.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an property called SelectedItem(of what type your collection your binding to is) and bind it to SelectedItem property of the ListBox. Then bind the Text property of the TextBlock to the SelectedItem property you defined as well.

Create the SelectedItem property:

```
public string SelectedItem
    {
        get { return selectedItem; }
        set { selectedItem = value; }
    }
```

and In your xaml :

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Sentences}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" Grid.Column="1" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}" />
```

Comment: Don't forget to set the DataContext of the hosting window.
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify ElementName property in textbox to specify the list box name

```
To solve this you should change your binding to the following:
<TextBlock ... Text="{Binding ElementName=pathListB, Path=SelectedItem.Content}" ... />
```

set the update source trigger in listbox to property changed